# Integration Testing Data Access Code For Sql

Tags: c#, .net, testing, integration-testing

I have a class named ***Database***  that implements following interface ;

```
 public interface IDatabase
{
    int ExecuteNonQuery(string command, CommandType commandType, Dictionary<string, object> parameters);
}
```

As the name indicates ***ExecuteNonQuery*** function executes non-query database commands in a provider agnostic way.

I need to write integration test for this class, and so far I've written an integration test for **Sql Server Compact Edition**  which passes the test.

Here is the integration test code ;

```
public class DatabaseIntegrationTests
{
    private readonly string CurrentDir;
    private readonly string SqlCeDbPath;

    public DatabaseIntegrationTests()
    {
        CurrentDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        SqlCeDbPath = CurrentDir + @"\TestDb.sdf";
    }

    [Fact]
    public void ExecuteNonQuery_SqlServerCE_Should_Execute()
    {
        var dbConfFunc = this.InitializeSqlServerCeInstance();
        Database database = new Database(dbConfFunc);
        database.ExecuteNonQuery("CREATE TABLE Test([ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,[Message] [nvarchar](255) NULL)",
            CommandType.Text, null);

        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        parameters.Add("@message", "Hello World!");
        database.ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO Test(Message) VALUES(@message)",
            CommandType.Text, parameters);

        CleanUpSqlServerCe();
    }
    private void CleanUpSqlServerCe()
    {
        if (File.Exists(SqlCeDbPath))
            File.Delete(SqlCeDbPath);
    }
    private Func<DbConnectionConfiguration> InitializeSqlServerCeInstance()
    {
        string connectionString = "Data Source=" + CurrentDir + @"\ASTest.sdf;Persist Security Info=False";

        CleanUpSqlServerCe();

        SqlCeEngine engine = new SqlCeEngine(connectionString);
        engine.CreateDatabase();

        return () =>
       {
           return new DbConnectionConfiguration()
           {
               DataProvider = "System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0",
               ConnectionString = connectionString
           };
       };
    }
}
```

My question is , how can write integration test for this class for  MySql and Sql Server database providers? 
What is the most practical way to write integration test for this class to test it for both MySql and Sql Server databases?

Comment: Identify the code most likely to change between tests and make an abstract base test class  which would allow for the necessary changes to be made for each test

Comment: Ask yourself what behavior you're trying to validate. You wrote a wrapper class so you can unit test other code that relies on the database. You don't need to test the wrapper explicitly. You should integration test the methods where you're using the database abstraction, which will thoroughly validate your wrapper.

Comment: @DanielMann Yes. It is a wrapper class for data access layer that supposed to work for mysql, sql server and sql server compact edition. Shouldn't i write an integration test for it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to test it for MySql , I've used  https://github.com/stumpdk/MySql.Server

Edit  : Note that, it doesn't support procedures.